# Custom Template 404 for specific custom post type

Tags: php, pages, templates, page-template

Some solution to create a custom template for (page 404) for specific custom post type.

Comment: if it's a 404 then how would you know which custom post type it was?

Comment: that is the point! I have seen that some pages made in wordpress, handle different 404, for different types of post

Comment: I haven't, do you have examples you can put in your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is going to track only `post_type` query var, but you also can add checks for `query_vars` of all your post_types or only ones you would like to get a custom 404 page for.

```
add_filter( '404_template_hierarchy', function( $templates ) {
    global $wp_query;

    if ( '' !== $wp_query->get('post_type') ) {
        array_unshift( $templates, 
            sprintf( '%s-404.php', $wp_query->get('post_type') ) );
    }

    return $templates;
});
```